# Apache7 with struts2 + struts2-json-plugin + jquery-ui autocomplete: Special characters not escaped properly

Tags: json, struts2, jquery-ui-autocomplete

hope you can help me with a problem:
I use Struts2 with the struts2-json-plugin, both in version 2.1.8.1. The JQuery-UI's version is 1.8.9. The whole shebang runs on Tomcat 7.0.8.
My problem is this: When I enter special characters (for example the name "Müller") into the search field, the method setTerm(String term) of my struts-action is called with parameter "mÃ¼ller". So, clearly, some encoding error occurs.

I defined a source Struts-Action for autocomplete, it's configuration-xml looks like this:

```
<action name="SearchUsers" class="...">
    <interceptor-ref name="..." />
    <result type="json">
        <param name="root">users</param>
            <param name="noCache">true</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

This is how I configured autocomplete on the web page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#nachname").autocomplete({
            source : "SearchUsers.action",
            dataType : "json",
            minLength : 3
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was hidden in Tomcat's server.xml. The Connector was like this:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

It was missing a URIEncoding="UTF-8" attribute:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

@toLowerCase me:
i am not sure if UTF-8 is supporting this or not,internally struts2 will be using UTF-8 encoding schema as default one.
So check if UTF-8 is the cause if it is so create a struts2.properties file and set your encoding something like.

```
### This can be used to set your default locale and encoding scheme
# struts.locale=en_US
struts.i18n.encoding=UTF-8
```

this is my assumption and i have not tried it at all,so all you can do is to play around..

Comment: Sadly for me, this is already set in my struts.properties file. Still: Many thanks for trying to help me out umesh! :-)

Comment: we are using simple theme in our application and its working fine can u try to set the them=simple in your struts2 radio tag to see what is happening?

Comment: I use a <s:textfield as input; autocomplete write an ID into a <s:hidden, wich is evaluated by the next action. I also use the "simple" theme. The resulting HTML looks like this: <input aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" role="textbox" autocomplete="off" name="..." value="" id="..." class="filter ui-autocomplete-input" type="text"><input name="...ID" value="" id="...ID" type="hidden">